# I'm brand new still a student and I'm trying to create temporary themes

Tags: themes, temporary

Ok so I'm learning how to write code in class but I'm trying to create temporary themes for the holidays is it possible and if so how

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by 'temporary themes'. Please show us what you have tried to accomplish this. Do you mean by adding a UI theme for your application?

Comment: no, I mean temporary like for the holidays or do I have to go in there every holiday and change it, and then after change it back. like I said I'm totally new to this and I'm literally still a student . I'm just trying to understand some of what my instructor is saying

Comment: what am I doing wrong <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<style>
body {
  background-color: linen;
}

h1 {
  color: maroon;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
<h1 style="color:blue;text-align:center;">My First Heading</h1>
<pstyle="color:red;">My first paragraph.</p>

</style>
</body>
</html>

Comment: You need to close your ``<style>`` tag. Delete your semicolon after your red color specification on your ``<p>`` style tag. See [this codepen](https://codepen.io/SOcodepen/pen/PoWzdvB) for more info.

Comment: Has your question been solved yet?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a system that updates your website's design dynamically in relation in time or manually change it yourself. This can be done automatically, where you have a dynamic system where a web server can update a design or stylesheet used or you could create a new design for your website's stylesheet and manually change it when you believe your temporary theme should be used.

If you are building a website, you could simply create another stylesheet in your relation to your normal specific design (such as changing your website's background color/text color), and link it to your main page with the `<style>` tag. If you would like to update the color automatically however, you would need to use a dynamic system/language, such as `PHP` or `ASP.NET` to update the website in however shape you would like.

There would be many possibilities you could accomplish this; there is not only "one" correct answer that would work and it's entirely up to you.